# Error to be thrown for gettimeofday failure

Tags: c++11

What error should be thrown for a failure due to gettimeofday ? I was looking at the list of exceptions. std::bad_exception looks like the  closest. Or should I be making my own exception ? It is a linux exception that can fail for several reasons. So leaving me confused.

1
std::exception
An exception and parent class of all the standard C++ exceptions.

2
std::bad_alloc
This can be thrown by new.

3
std::bad_cast
This can be thrown by dynamic_cast.

4
std::bad_exception
This is useful device to handle unexpected exceptions in a C++ program.

5
std::bad_typeid
This can be thrown by typeid.

6
std::logic_error
An exception that theoretically can be detected by reading the code.

7
std::domain_error
This is an exception thrown when a mathematically invalid domain is used.

8
std::invalid_argument
This is thrown due to invalid arguments.

9
std::length_error
This is thrown when a too big std::string is created.

10
std::out_of_range
This can be thrown by the 'at' method, for example a std::vector and std::bitset<>::operator.

11
std::runtime_error
An exception that theoretically cannot be detected by reading the code.

12
std::overflow_error
This is thrown if a mathematical overflow occurs.

13
std::range_error
This is occurred when you try to store a value which is out of range.

14
std::underflow_error
This is thrown if a mathematical underflow occurs.

Comment: I'd say either runtime_error or define your own. Although this question is opinion-based so you're not going to get any 'correct' answer.

Comment: `bad_exception` is *not* the right one. Where the description says "unexpected exception", it actually means "unexpected C++ exception".